# Check whole file if name exists

Tags: c++

I tried to parse each data from file to `student.name` and `student.pass` to get only the `student.name`. I was successfully able to get all the `student.name`, but what I want to happen is after checking each line, then I can compare if all the `student.name` contains name, or if name exists.

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%[^:]%*c%[^\n]%*c", &student.name, &student.pass) != EOF)
            {
                printf("Username is %s\n", student.name);
                if(strcmp(student.name, a)==0)
                {
                    cout << "Exists" << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Not Exists" << endl;
                }
            }
```

What happened in this code is that it checks each line and compares. When I try to put the if else condition after the while condition, it can only check the last data.

How am I able to compare the name to all the student.name from the file?

Comment: Can you give one example for your requirement?

Comment: the file you mean?

Comment: the file based on the input and the format of each input is fprintf(fp, "%s:%s\n", student.name, student.pass);

Comment: No. What I understood from your question is, you want to put if..else.. block outside the while loop right? Why do you want to do that? Because this logic looks fine for me.

Comment: Since the code you posted is not complete, I can't run it and make suggestions.  I don't want to guess on the part that's missing - might be a huge waste of my time.  Why not include a complete, verifiable example - eg something I can compile and run?

Comment: i have posted the whole program. what I need is check all the student.name then compare, but what happens is that it compare each student.name.

Comment: I need to insert some function when data is not exists, but what happens here is that it checks each  data from the file, but not all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a [vector](/questions/tagged/vector) and put your data in that.

So the part of your while loop snippet becomes:

```
#include <vector>
//...

  std::vector<accout> accouts;
  while(...) {
    accouts.push_back(student);
  }
  //process accouts here
```

Comment: After parsing, I put all the data to vector then from there, compare the new data to existing data

Comment: After parsing, I put all the data to vector then from there, compare the new data to existing data

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to put the

```
    if(strcmp(student.name, a)==0)
        {
            cout << "Exists" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Not Exists" << endl;
        }
```

outside the while loop. By doing so, in your while loop you will just parse all the entries in the file until you get to the last and then you will exit the while loop. After this, it will compare the last name from the file with the name you want to search. Think about the situation when you iterate through a vector in order to check if a value x is equal to a value from the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You are making your life horribly difficult by the hodge-podge of C/C++ you are mixing together, when C++ streams, and `getline` (with a delimiter of `':'`) provide all you need.

The example below uses an `istringstream` to hold sample data to read. Just replace it with `fstream` to read from a file.

While you generally want to store all data you read from a file, simply declare `tmp` account struct to read into and a `vector` of your account struct, to hold all data you `.push_back (tmp);` into the vector e.g.

```
    account tmp;                    /* temp account to read from file */
    ...
    std::vector<account> students;  /* vector of accounts to hold students */

    while (getline(is, tmp.name, ':') &&    /* while name & pass read */
            getline(is, tmp.pass))
        students.push_back (tmp);           /* add to vector students */
```

Now your vector of accounts `students` holds all the `name` and `pass` information for each student. You now prompt the user for a name to search and simply loop over the stored names, e.g.

```
    std::string search;             /* string to hold search */
    ...
    std::cout << "enter name to search: ";  /* get search term */
    if (getline (std::cin, search)) {
        for (auto& s : students)            /* loop over structs */
            if (s.name == search) {         /* comparing names to search */
                std::cout << "found: " << s.name 
                << "  (pass: " << s.pass << ")\n";
                goto namefound; /* if found a quick goto to jump not-found */
            }
        std::cerr << "name not found: " << search << '\n';
  namefound:;
    }
```

That's done. It loops until it finds a match and then just uses a simple `goto` to just over the default output that is presented if no match is found. (yes, the `goto` still have very limited but very valuable uses even today)

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <iostream> /* use C++ streams and containers */
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct account {    /* your struct */
    std::string name, pass;
};

int main (void) {

    account tmp;                    /* temp account to read from file */
    std::string search;             /* string to hold search */
    std::vector<account> students;  /* vector of accounts to hold students */
    std::istringstream is ( "Mary Jane:12345\n"     /* data - replace */
                            "John Doe:45678" );     /* with your file */

    while (getline(is, tmp.name, ':') &&    /* while name & pass read */
            getline(is, tmp.pass))
        students.push_back (tmp);           /* add to vector students */

    std::cout << "enter name to search: ";  /* get search term */
    if (getline (std::cin, search)) {
        for (auto& s : students)            /* loop over structs */
            if (s.name == search) {         /* comparing names to search */
                std::cout << "found: " << s.name 
                << "  (pass: " << s.pass << ")\n";
                goto namefound; /* if found a quick goto to jump not-found */
            }
        std::cerr << "name not found: " << search << '\n';
  namefound:;
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Input**

```
$ /bin/studentpass
enter name to search: John Smith
name not found: John Smith

$ ./bin/studentpass
enter name to search: John Doe
found: John Doe  (pass: 45678)

$ ./bin/studentpass
enter name to search: Mary Jane
found: Mary Jane  (pass: 12345)
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.